# How do you view a log of previous visited visitors showing their IP in Drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

Where do you view a log of previous visitors showing their IP address in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find visitors IP-adresses in both the `session`table (field `hostname`) or, if you have the core **statistics** module enabled, in the `accesslog` table (field `hostname`).

You can view these logs in a tool that let you examine your database (I use *phpMyAdmin*), or you can write a small custom module that displays them for you.

Comment: In addition to enabling the Statistics module, you need to enable the access log at /admin/config/system/statistics to have IP addresses tracked in that table.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at admin/reports/dblog, you filter the messages by type, and set the type to user, the list will show which users logged in; when you click on the link shown under "Message," you will get the IP of each user.